# Angular "multiple" value filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

I need some help with angular filter. I need to filter array by multiple values in one field.

Array looks like this:

```
$scope.items = [{
  "item": "one",
  "tags": "2,5"
}, {
  "item": "two",
  "tags": "3,4,6,7"
}, {
  "item": "three",
  "tags": "1,3,5"
}];
```

I want to search items by tags that are separated by comma.

Example: in search field user input tags separated with comma (or select by checkbox) and select tags 1 and 3. How to list all items that have those tags? In this example second and third item.

**Plunker**

https://plnkr.co/edit/6SidABYsjtrjtH3xqusA?p=preview

Comment: can you make a plunkr with your code it will be better to resolve your issue

Comment: Is there a reason why your tags are a comma separated string? Would it not be better for them to be arrays? I.e: `"tags": [1,3,5]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your required answer using the checkboxes.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('Controller', function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [{
      "name": "one",
      "tags": "2,5"
    }, {
      "name": "two",
      "tags": "3,4,6,7"
    }, {
      "name": "three",
      "tags": "1,3,5"
    }];

    $scope.items_dup = $scope.items
    // checkbox selection
    $scope.selection = [];
    $scope.toggleSelection = function toggleSelection(filter) {
      var idx = $scope.selection.indexOf(filter);
      if (idx > -1) {
        $scope.selection.splice(idx, 1);
      } else {
        $scope.selection.push(filter);
      }
    };

    // filter list
    $scope.filter = function() {
      filterTag($scope.selection,$scope.items);
      function filterTag(selected,items){
        var out = [];
        angular.forEach(items, function(value, key) {
          angular.forEach(selected, function(inner_value, key) {
            if(value.tags.split(',').indexOf(inner_value.toString()) > -1)
            {
              if(out.indexOf(value) == -1)
              {
                out.push(value)
              }
            }
          })
        })
        if(out.length > 0)
        {
          $scope.items_dup = out;
        }
        else
        {
          $scope.items_dup = $scope.items;   
        }
      }
      
    };
  })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="Controller">
    <h1>Tag filter!</h1>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items_dup">
      {{item.name}}
    </li>
    <hr>
    <p>Select filter</p>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="1" ng-click="toggleSelection(1)"> 1
    </label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="2" ng-click="toggleSelection(2)"> 2
    </label><br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="3" ng-click="toggleSelection(3)"> 3
    </label>
    <br><br>
    <button ng-click="filter()">Filter list</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Please run the code snippet and check.**

[Here is the plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/M4ccOyRVAPPhDzyCbOf4?p=preview)

Comment: Sravan this is great, but my tags are not array, that is the problem. And I'm not able to convert that in array on data source. How to modify your solution to take comma separated tags?

Comment: updated both plunker and answer with the string format. pls check.

Comment: Please I need some help. There were some changes in filters. Problem is that filer is showing all products of selected filter, but we don't want that. Plunker is here: https://plnkr.co/edit/vr9o2aHkHvCL1cvgKILd?p=preview So when user select product with 1GHz and black color we dont want to show any products.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <table>
     <tr>
        <td align="right">Search :</td>
        <td><input ng-model="query" /></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td align="right">Search By :</td>
        <td>
           <select ng-model="query">
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
              <option value="4">4</option>
           </select>
        </td>
     </tr>
  </table>
  <hr>
  <div>
     <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in items | filter:query">
           <td>{{item.item}}</td>
        </tr>
     </table>



  var employeeApp = angular.module("EmployeeApp",[]);
  employeeApp.controller("empCtrl",function($scope){

    $scope.items = [{
      "item": "one",
      "tags": "2,5"
    }, {
      "item": "two",
      "tags": "3,4,6,7"
    }, {
      "item": "three",
      "tags": "1,3,5"
    }];
    $scope.orderProp="";                
  });
```